# How do I remove the hyperlink status from a specific word in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, hyperlink

If I paste a URL into a Notepad++ document, then (because I have "Enable" checked under Settings > Preferences > MISC > Clickable Link Settings > Clickable Link Settings) it becomes a clickable hyperlink. This is not a problem. This is what I want to happen.

But if this hyperlink accidentally comes into contact with another word (through backspacing or deleting or typing immediately after the URL), then this other word *also* becomes a clickable hyperlink. This transformation is a problem. It wouldn't be a big problem, if I could quickly reverse it. But Ctrl-Z doesn't reverse it, and I cannot find a way to remove the hyperlink status from the unlucky word.

Here is an animated gif illustrating the problem:

[image: Hyperlink.gif]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of Npp? Here v7.4.2

Comment: I'm also using v7.4.2 in Windows 10. What happens when you imitate the behavior shown in the gif?

Comment: I've done exactly the same and at the end the word `test` is not clickable.

Comment: @76987 Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple methods to approach this:

The quickest way to reverse it, as you requested, is probably go over the selected text you want, Copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and Paste it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). This simply replaces what you have with what you have and refreshes the text editor to look for pre-existing hyperlinks. *But*, the text that was attached must be detached.

Better yet, you could also change the editor's Language to "User-Defined" (under the Language drop-down). This is essentialy a blank language (unless you created one already) like the "Normal Text" language. With the blank "User-Defined" language, it will automatically dissociate the detached text from being a hyperlink (like in the example demo you showed) and you don't have to repeatedly do the copy paste method nor below.

Lastly, the most sloppiest and long way to do it is by changing the language to something else and changing it back to what you already had (I would assume you're using "Normal Text"). This will remove all hyperlinks from the document and all you have to do is update the text at the hyperlink in order for it to recognize it as a hyperlink.

Good Luck.